# Overriding Card titleStyle and subtitleStyle not working in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have to apply different styles for title and subtitle elements of Card components using Material-ui.

Following is my code:

```
const mediaTitleStyles = {
  ....
  ....
  title:{
    fontSize: 35,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  subtitle:{
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },

};

<Card>

    <CardMedia style={{background: '#9E9E9E'}}
     overlay={<CardTitle title="LIVE THE LANGUAGE" subtitle="Learn a language based on the situations that are relevant to you." />}
     overlayContentStyle={mediaTitleStyles.content}
     titleStyle = {mediaTitleStyles.title} subtitleStyle={mediaTitleStyles.subtitle}
    >
    .................
```

Basically, I am trying to apply different font-size for those two elements. But, the output is not working? Do I have to include anything?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add style directly in the CardTitle component:

```
....
<CardMedia style={{background: '#9E9E9E'}}
 overlay={
    <CardTitle 
        titleStyle = {mediaTitleStyles.title}
        subtitleStyle={mediaTitleStyles.subtitle} 
        title="LIVE THE LANGUAGE" 
        subtitle="Learn a language based on the situations that are relevant to you." 
    />}
 overlayContentStyle={mediaTitleStyles.content}    
>....
```

Answer (score 1):

subtitleStyle is a CardHeader property .
Please check applying it the the card header as below

```
<CardHeader
    subtitleStyle={{color:"red"}}
    subtitle={"An Example!!"}
    .
    .
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the below coding parameters I'm giving some example for you, hope this help to figure out your issues,

```
    <CardTitle expand style={{alignItems: 'flex-start', color: '#fff'}}>
      <h4 style={{marginTop: '0'}}>
        Featured event:<br />
        May 24, 2016<br />
        7-11pm
      </h4>
    </CardTitle>
```

and you can also use

```
    <CardText>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
    </CardText>
```

here are some resource that you can have a look at,

https://github.com/tleunen/react-mdl

and here are some documentation with examples,

https://tleunen.github.io/react-mdl/components/card/